# Can anyone explain what the second corollary in Newton's Principia is about?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, vectors

I was reading  but it is unclear to me what Newton is trying to say in his second corollary, it is in the page 91 of the pdf and 84 of the book here is a photo of the proposition

[image: What I understood is that he is trying to find the force which pulls the weights A and P down and the relationship betwwen the two and it's components with the radius of the wheel but I don't fully understand the result and if it has any particular meaning in modern language what does it say in algebraic notation?]

Comment: *page 91 of the pdf* What PDF? Please provide a link to it.

Comment: This is an excellent example of how something extremely simple in modern pedagogy used to be something horrendously complicated using Newton’s opaque geometrical methods.

Comment: There are a number of webpages which explain in modern terms what Newton was deriving. eg [Link](https://publishing.cdlib.org/ucpressebooks/view?docId=ft4489n8zn&chunk.id=d0e16248&toc.depth=1&toc.id=d0e16248&brand=ucpress)

Answer (score 6):

He is explaining how to add forces, and justifying why it is a reasonable procedure. In modern terms, he is describing vector addition.

Comment: https://redlightrobber.com/red/links_pdf/Isaac-Newton-Principia-English-1846.pdf

Comment: The second sentence of your answer is ambiguous. In modern language, Newton justifies that the set of forces is a vector space with their physical composition rule. Your sentence can be interpreted as if Newton was doing math while he was doing physics: he was describing how the world works.